# Android Studio Emulator not running.

Tags: android

When I try to run app and select from my available emulators I try to pick one and I get the error message "minSdk(API 23, N preview) != deviceSdk(API23)". Can't figure out what's wrong or how to get it running.

Answer (score 1):

Apps built for the N preview with jack can currrenty only be run in an N emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem many days ago while i was trying to study android studio in Linux. So I read the document of google and found that only android studio 2.1 supports the android N. So I downloaded the newest version of android studio 2.1 and then installed it. Then, the problem just disappeared.
Here is the download link:
http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/latest